# ODE question about defining certain values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A parachutist whose mass is 100 kg drops from a helicopter hovering 3000 m above the ground and falls under the influence of gravity. Assume that the force due to air resistance is proportional to the velocity of the parachutist, with the proportionality constant k1 = 20 kg/sec when the chute is closed and k2 = 100 kg/sec when the chute is open. If the chute does not open until 30 seconds after the parachutist leaves the helicopter, after how many seconds will they reach the ground? If the chute does not open until 1 minute after they leave the helicopter, after how many seconds will they reach the ground?

I know the expression I have to refer to is $$m\frac{dv}{dt} = mg - kv$$

I know that this involves two expressions, mainly when $k = 30$ and $k = 100$. I have solved the two ODEs but I am lost on what to do.

1) What is v? Is that the velocity?
2) I would generally like an outline of how to solve this word problem; I can solve the linear ODEs, but I have no idea on the method to solve it.

Comment: Note: You say "$k=30$", where I think you meant $k=20$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is positive, then $v$ is downward velocity. If $g$ is negative, then $v$ is upward velocity. It doesn't really affect the problem which it is as long as you're consistent and handle the initial/final heights correctly.

How you're supposed to solve this problem may depend on your background, but one way to do it would be to define $k$ as a piecewise function of time: $k=\begin{cases}
20 & \text{ if }t<30\\
100 & \text{ if }t\ge30
\end{cases}$ and then solve the differential equation (either by manually connecting solutions on the two intervals, or using a Laplace transform). That tells you $v$, but then you need to find height as a function of time to figure out when height is zero. And then see how the answer changes if you replace $30$ with the number of seconds in a minute.